# How to do promise inside promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, axios, es6-promise

I am trying to do pagination with promise. Here's my workflow.

**Step 1 :** Total page in pagination is 50. The url will be like `url?page=1`

**Step 2 :** In each page i will get 50 products, which i need to call a seperate api.

The only condition is, during pagination, the second page should called only if first page's 50 api call is done. Once all the 50 pages are fetched, it should return the promise.

What  i have so far is.

```
let promises = [];
paginate(50);
Promise.all(promises)
  .catch(function(err) {
  console.log('err',err);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('All Done!!!!!');
});

function paginate(loop){
promises.push(
    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        // Got 50 products
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('err',err);
    })
)
```

In the place `Got 50 products` i need to still iterate the 50 products in axios. I am not sure whether it is possible to do promise inside promise.

As the server can't bear all sudden loads, the only condition is to iterate the second 50 products (or next page's products) only after first (or previous 50 api is called).

**Edit :**

// Here i have got 50 products
As i told, On each page i will get 50 products, i will call another api for all those 50 products. I have given the code below.

Only constraint is on first page response, the response 50's api should be called.. it's like `product?product=1` . the next 50 should be called only after first 50's api called

```
for (let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
const element = response[index];
    //Here call api for one item 
    axios(config)
    .then(function (elemen t) {
        // Here i have got 50 products
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('err',err);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not looking for `Promise.all` *(which is meant for running things in parallel)*, but for recursion:

```js
fetchPages(0, 49)
.then(console.log);

function fetchPages(from, to, results = []) {
  if (from <= to) {
    return fetchPage(from)
           .then(res => results.push(...res))
           .then(() => fetchPages(from + 1, to, results)); // calls itself
  } else {
    return results;
  }
}

function fetchPage(n) {
  console.log(`Fetching page ${n}`);
  // Here, you would return axios()...
  // But just for this demo, I fake that:
  const results = new Array(50).fill(null)
                               .map((_,i) => `Product ${i} from page ${n}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(results), 100));
}
```

---

**Edit**

The code above solves the problem of pages needing to be fetched only one after the other. We can keep the `fetchPages` function as it is. Now, since every page will contain products which will need to be fetched individually, we'll just edit `fetchPage` a bit.

There are multiple ways this could be done. Here are some:

**Solution A: fetch every product in parallel**

If the server can handle 50 requests going off at once, you could use `Promise.all`:

```
function fetchPage(n) {
  console.log(`Fetching page ${n}`);
  return axios(`/page?page=${n}`)
         .then(productIds => {
           return Promise.all(productIds.map(fetchProduct));
         });
}

function fetchProduct(id) {
  return axios(`/product?product=${id}`);
}
```

**Solution B: fetch every product in sequence**

If the server can't handle multiple requests going off at once, you could use recursion once again:

```
function fetchPage(n) {
  console.log(`Fetching page ${n}`);
  return axios(`/page?page=${n}`)
         .then(fetchproducts);
}

function fetchProducts(productIds, results = []) {
  if (productIds.length) {
    const productId = productIds.shift();
    return fetchProduct(productId)
           .then(res => results.push(res))
           .then(() => fetchProducts(productIds, results)); // calls itself
  } else {
    return results;
  }
}

function fetchProduct(id) {
  return axios(`/product?product=${id}`);
}
```

**Solution C: fetch products X requests at a time**

If the server can handle X requests going off at once, you could use a module like [queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue), which can help you with concurrency:

```
const queue = require('queue'); // Don't forget to $ npm install queue
const MAX_CONCURRENT_CALLS = 4; // 4 calls max at any given time

function fetchPage(n) {
  console.log(`Fetching page ${n}`);
  return axios(`/page?page=${n}`)
         .then(fetchproducts);
}

function fetchProducts(productIds) {
  const q = queue();
  q.concurrency = MAX_CONCURRENT_CALLS;
  const results = [];

  q.push(
    ...productIds.map(productId => () => {
      return fetchProduct(productId)
             .then(product => results.push(product));
    })
  );

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    q.start(function (err) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(results);
    });
  });
}

function fetchProduct(id) {
  return axios(`/product?product=${id}`);
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering.. in the // Got 50 products, i will call each api for 1 product.. it will be like for One page it will be 50 calls and so on... sorry i will edit the question and be more specific .. .

Comment: @SA__ Ok, I edited my answer. I think Solution C is the best, as it allows you to fine tune the maximum number of requests you want to be going out at any given time, to minimize server load, but still be able to have some concurrency

Comment: Hi @blex thank you so much , i will use the solution c.. thanks a lot